# error invalid conversion from 'float*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, function

Ok so, i'm trying to covnert some number into others via function. The vector "tempc" contains 7 celsius numbers. The type "tempf" will contain fahrenheit. But i get this error in the title "error invalid conversion from 'float*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]". I'm new to programming , so i'm kinda really newbie. Sorry for the code but it's in italian

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//dichiarazione variabili e vettori
float tempc[7] = {23,25,22,19,18,20,16};
float tempf[7];
const int MAX_GRADI = 7;

//funzione conversione
int ConversioneInF ()
{
    for (int i=0;i<MAX_GRADI;i++)
        tempf[i]=(9/5)*tempc[i]+32; //C in F
    return tempf;

}

int main () 
{
    ConversioneInF();
    for (int i=0;i<MAX_GRADI;i++)
        cout<<"La temperatura in fahrenheit e' :"<<tempf[i]<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `9/5` is exactly `1` in c++ because they are integers. `9.0/5` is approximately `1.8`.

Comment: Your function has the return type `int` but you are trying to return an array of `float`. What do you intend for the return value of `ConversioneInF ` to mean?

Comment: Your `tempf` is global, there is no need to return anything from your function.

Comment: Why is your `ConversioneInF` has `int` return type? Why do you `return tempf` from it? Can you explain the purpose of these things? And please don't use global variables.

Comment: Your loop has misleading indentation, and the loop body should really have `{}`. Unfortunately these two errors cancel out

Answer (score 2):

In your function `ConversioneInf` you are returning `tempf`.
This is a float-array, which in c++ is a pointer to float (`float*`)
This type cannot be converted to the specified return type `int`.
As you are not using the return value, just change it to void:

```
void ConversioneInF ()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void ConversioneInF ()
{
    for (int i=0;i<MAX_GRADI;i++)
        tempf[i]=(9.0/5.0)*tempc[i]+32;
}
```

Anyway, tempf is global, you don't need to return it.